# MonoDroid: Speeding up Simulator

Tags: xamarin.android

I am looking for tips on speeding up the Android Simulator, especially when run from MonoDroid.

Currently the simulator works, but at a speed much lower than when we write with Eclipse and debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you referring to app startup, or normal execution after app startup?

App startup will be slower (Mono for Android does quite a bit of work during app startup), but once things are running (and the methods have been JITed) performance should be reasonable (considering it's the emulator, perhaps not quite reasonable).